# how can i make typescript simulated pointer?

Tags: javascript, function, typescript

I want to simulated pointer "like in  JAVA" to point to my new object of class in typescript or javascript
 see link below ?
http://postimg.org/image/9za5xagoj/
http://tinypic.com/r/fdet8p/9

```
 class Asset{
item:string
mainBeneficiary: EntitlementArray[];
equalshare:boolean
substituteSet: EntitlementArray[];  
    }

assets:Asset ;
//points  to only "Asset"  
pointer : Asset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var pointer = Asset; 
var instance = new pointer()
```

[View Example on TypeScript-Playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Asset%7B%0Aitem%3Astring%0AmainBeneficiary%3A%20EntitlementArray%5B%5D%3B%0Aequalshare%3Aboolean%0AsubstituteSet%3A%20EntitlementArray%5B%5D%3B%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0Aassets%3AAsset%20%3B%0A%2F%2Fpoints%20%20to%20only%20%22Asset%22%20%20%0Avar%20pointer%20%3D%20Asset%3B%20)